# How can I force an image to display in its entirety with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, gif

I have a small icon (17 X 17) that links to a page which I'm trying to display like so:

```
<a class="finaff-small-pdf-form-icon" href="/Financial_Affairs_Forms/Payee_Setup_204.pdf">Payee Setup 204</a>
```

The CSS class referenced is defined thus:

```
.finaff-small-pdf-form-icon {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-image: url("/_layouts/images/pdficon.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The icon:

[image]

../gets truncated at the bottom, though:

[image]

I tried the following with background-size in the CSS class:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 80px 60px;
background-size: contain;
```

...but none of them made any difference.

How can I get the icon to show all of itself, even its feet?

Comment: What made you try `background-size: 80px 60px;`? Have you tried `background-size: 20px 20px;` or `background-size: 17px 17px;`?

Comment: Try to set the width and height of your class (finaff-small-pdf-form-icon). Also use display incline-block.

Comment: Can you make a snippet that demonstrates the issue? I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/x131ofex/), but it has no problems displaying the whole image.

Comment: I also tried it with no issue, please give us a fiddle!

Comment: @Pablo: I suppose you meant inline.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, yes!  that was my mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided works fine. I have created a fiddle using your existing styling and HTML:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqxpaL36/)

**HTML**

```
<a class="finaff-small-pdf-form-icon" href="/Financial_Affairs_Forms/Payee_Setup_204.pdf">Payee Setup 204</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.finaff-small-pdf-form-icon {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIXOF.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I presume your issue is coming from parent styles that are being applied to containing elements on your page. You should look at the browser's developer console for more clarification on what is causing that styling issue (<kbd>F12</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
.finaff-small-pdf-form-icon:before {
    content: url("/_layouts/images/pdficon.gif");
    display: inline-block;
    height: 17px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 17px;
}
.finaff-small-pdf-form-icon {
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That removes the icon entirely; at least it shows me, though, that changes to the class really are being propagated.

Comment: Can you show me your full structure which wraps this element

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ends up working for me:

```
.finaff-small-pdf-form-icon {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 18px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIXOF.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The key addition (line-height changed, too, but doubtless the original value would still be fine) was:

```
display: block;
```

For fuller disclosure, the HTML previously shown is embedded within a div like so:

```
<div class="JS_Toggle_Holder_Content">
    <a class="finaff-small-pdf-form-icon" href="/Financial_Affairs_Forms/Payee_Setup_204.pdf">Payee Setup 204</a>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS class referenced:

```
.JS_Toggle_Holder_Content {width: 96%; padding: 5px; margin: 5px auto; border: 1px solid #ddd; display: none; background: #fff;}
```